# Documenting first-class-assigned functions

Tags: python, coding-style, docstring, first-class-functions, numpy-ufunc

I have a function defined by making use of the first-class nature of Python functions, as follows:

```
add_relative = np.frompyfunc(lambda a, b: (1 + a) * (1 + b) - 1, 2, 1)
```

Either I need a way to add a docstring to the function defined as it is, or achieve the same thing using the more common format, so that I can write a docstring in the normal way:

```
def add_relative(a, b):
    """
    Docstring
    """
    return np.frompyfunc(lambda a, b: (1 + a) * (1 + b) - 1, 2, 1)(a, b)
```

which works when the function is called like

```
 add_relative(arr1, arr2)
```

but I then lose the ability to call methods, for example

```
add_relative.accumulate(foo_arr, dtype=np.object)
```

I guess this is because the function becomes more like a class when using `frompyfunc`, being derived from `ufunc`.

I'm thinking I might need to define a class, rather than a function, but I'm not sure how. I would be ok with that because then I can easily add a docstring as normal.

I tagged this `coding-style` because the original method works but simply can't be easily documented, and I'm sorry if the title is not clear, I don't know the correct vocabulary to describe this.

Comment: I guess it should be noted that the function defined in the first way does come with a docstring, but I wish to add my own/overwrite this (which is not possible by `add_relative.__doc__ = 'string'`).

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to define a class with `numpy.ufunc` as a base class. Doing so throws the error `TypeError: type 'numpy.ufunc' is not an acceptable base type`. I don't really want to have to write an entire function from scratch just to be able to add a docstring, when the initial function definition performs perfectly.

Comment: In general, the docstring of a function defined in the initial way can be updated by assigning to the `__doc__` attribute, but that is not appropriate here as this attribute is immutable for a `numpy.ufunc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 1:**
Close, but this still isn't good enough. Because the `__doc__` attribute of the decorated function cannot be updated, and because Sphinx still only picks up the docstring of the decorated function, this doesn't solve my problem.

**Update 2:**
The solution that I proposed below is nice for documentation within the source code. For documentation with Sphinx I ended up just overwriting the docstring with

```
.. function:: sum_relative(a, b)

   <Docstring written in rst format>
```

It's ugly, it's hacky and it's manual but it means that I have my nice documentation in the source code, and I have my nice documentation in Sphinx.

All of the issues stem from the fact that the `__doc__` attribute of a `numpy.ufunc` is immutable. If anyone knows why, I'd love to hear why. I'm guessing something related to the fact that it comes from something written in C, not pure Python. Regardless, it's very annoying.

---

I found that I could solve the issue using a decorator to apply `np.frompyfunc()`.

I write the base function (the lambda in the original example) and add a docstring as normal and then apply the decorator:

```
def as_ufunc(func):
    return np.frompyfunc(func, 2, 1)

@as_ufunc
def sum_relative(a, b):
    """
    Docstring
    """
    return (1 + a) * (1 + b) - 1
```

It's not a perfect solution for the following reasons:

- `sum_relative.__doc__` is overwritten by `frompyfunc` to a generic and unhelpful docstring. I don't mind here because I really care about the docs generated with Sphinx from the docstring, and not accessing it programatically. You might think to try something like `functools.wraps` or `functools.update_wrapper`, however the `__doc__` member of a `numpy.ufunc` is apparenly immutable.
- I have to hardcode the second two arguments for `frompyfunc`. I don't mind here because all the cases that I use it here will require the same values.
- Edit: It is possible to get around the above point, it's a little more verbose, but not much:

  ```
  def as_ufunc(nin, nout):
      def _decorator(func):
          return np.frompyfunc(func, nin, nout)
      return _decorator

  @as_ufunc(2, 1)
  def sum_relative(a, b):
      """
      Docstring
      """
      return (1 + a) * (1 + b) - 1
  ```
- It's more verbose than the original solution. I don't mind because I now have the docstring.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this might work:

```py
UFUNC_ATTRS = (
    'nin',
    'accumulate',
    # etc...
)


def redirectattribtues(destination):
    def decorator(func):
        for attribute in UFUNC_ATTRS:
            setattr(func, attribute, getattr(destination, attribute))
        return func
    return decorator


ufunc = np.frompyfunc(lambda a, b: (1 + a) * (1 + b) - 1, 2, 1)


@redirectattribtues(destination=ufunc)
def add_relative(a, b):
    """
    Docstring
    """
    return ufunc(a, b)


# test
arr1 = np.array(list(range(0, 10)))
arr2 = np.array(list(range(10, 20)))
print(add_relative(arr1, arr2))
print(add_relative.accumulate(arr1, dtype=object))
```